# Xpath How to get text with html tag

Tags: java, html, xpath, htmlcleaner

```
<div class="content pb10">
        some text<img src="URL"/>
</div>
```

Like this. I want to use XPath to get text with img tag

```
some text<img src="URL"/>
```

Comment: @kjhughes I tried this, but it not working. "Unknown function node!"

Comment: That error does not make sense for the XPath shown in my answer.  You're either making a mistake or using a non-compliant XPath processor.  My bet is on the former, but you've not shown enough for us to point out exactly what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
/div[@class='content pb10']/node()
```

will select all children nodes of that `div`, including text nodes and elements, as requested.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I am still unsure if it will satisfy the questioners needs - not due to your failing, but due to the lack of precision of the question.

Comment: @zx485: Thanks, and agreed.  It's unusual to request text and element node siblings together.  We'll see where OP takes it from here.